# $q.all With Recursion?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, recursion, q

I have a function making recursive calls. The structure looks something like this:

```
var getData = function(data){
  makeDbCall().then(function(response){
    if(response.something === someCondition){
      foreach(object in response)
        getData(object ); //calls itself over and over 
      }
    }
  )
};
```

The general idea (to avoid being off topic) is to, say, get all hotels in a city, all rooms in those hotels, all furniture in those rooms, etc. A normal $q.all foreach call is something like [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/NGMp4ycmaCqVOmgohN53?p=preview) - the function defines:

```
var promises = [];
```

and then returns $q.all:

```
return $q.all(promises);
```

My problem is that I don't know where to return $q.all from - if I return it from "getData", it returns on the first iteration of the recursion, and (as I understand) may not include the subsequent iterations if the initial calls resolve before the new ones pushed.

If I return it AFTER the `getData()` call, I get the same problem because as we all know, javascript continues without waiting for calls unless we defer.

I realize this question is vague, and I am completely fine with a vague response. I am just trying to see if I am missing something absolutely basic or if this is impossible. (I do know how to do it in a very dirty manner, but I would really love to use $q.all somehow).

[Here is the actual function that I am trying to wait for with call values changed for sake of example.](http://plnkr.co/edit/KIvtzADasOK84QctJnn7?p=preview)

Comment: Do you want the `getData` functions to execute sequentially or in parallel? Do the `getData` functions return promises?

Comment: Parallel. Otherwise I would just chain them like vittore suggested. makeDbCall() is automatically a promise whether its http or Restangular, getData CAN return $q.all(promises), the question is whether it should. I think I am just going to do this the "ghetto" way and compare count to returned object list length.

Answer (score 1):

I tried something by nesting promise resolution like following :

```
function getData(){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject)){
    for(let item of response){
      getData(item).then((res)=>{
        resolve(res);
      },(err)=>{
        reject(err);
      });
    }
  }
}
```

The trick is to use promise each time you can. This way you are able to have a resolution of your top level promise only when the childs are resolved too allowing you to make async recursion.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am not sure how that's different from assigning the call to a variable and pushing it to the promises array though. Maybe I am over-thinking and it will all chain though. Testing.

Answer (score 1):

One of the things you might do is to chain promises in your original array of promises, and use map to get promises for each element in array, ie consider this snipet

```
function getHotels(city) { return ajaxPromise ...  }
function getRooms(hotel) { ... } 
function getFurniture(room) { ... } 
function showUI(furniture) { ... }

getHotels(city).then(function(hotels) {
  return $q.all(hotels.map( h => getRooms(h)))
}).then(function(hotelRooms) {
  return $q.all(hotelRooms.map (hr => getFurniture(hr)))
}).then(showUI)
```

Comment: I might end up doing this, but from what I understand, this will be much slower since it's not spamming calls as rapidly this way. Appreciate the reply!

Answer (score 1):

For starters ---

> This methodology is deprecated

```
app.factory('json',function($q,$http){
    return function(files){
        var promises = [];
        angular.forEach(files, function(file){
            var deffered  = $q.defer();
            $http({
                   url : file,
                   method: 'GET'
            }).success(function(data){
                   deffered.resolve(data);
            }).error(function(error){
                   deffered.reject();
            });
            promises.push(deffered.promise);
        }) 
        return $q.all(promises);
    }
});
```

The `.success` and `.error` methods of the `$http` methods are **deprecated**. For more information see the [AngularJS $http Service API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).

The preferred way is:

```
app.factory('json',function($q,$http){
    return function(files){
        var promises = [];
        angular.forEach(files, function(file){
            var promise =
                $http({
                       url : file,
                       method: 'GET'
                      })
            promises.push(promise);
        }) 
        return promises;
    }
});
```

You can then process each of the returned promises individually or use `$q.all`. Be aware that `$q.all` is **not resilient**. The first promise to be rejected will skip the `.then` method and only first rejection will be caught by the `.catch` method.

```
var promiseList = json(files);

$q.all(promiseList).then (function (responseList) {
     //executes only if all promises ok
     $scope.dataList = doSomethingWith(responseList);
}). catch (error) { function (error)
     //executes with first error
     //log error
});
```

To process a promise individually:

```
promiseList[0].then (function (result) {
                   //save data
                   $scope.dataList[0] = result.data;
            }).catch (function (error) {
                   //log error
            });
```

Notice that the `.then` and `.catch` methods return data differently than the `.success` and `.error` methods.